# Sorting a hand of cards accoring to rank and suit in python

Tags: python

I'm tying to make a card game and at the moment I'm working on the beginning of it. What I am confused on is sorting the cards in a hand by their rank then suit and pretty much how to cut down on repetition. At the moment I could probably make a for loop for organizing the cards and then have 52 different if for each possibility but I was wondering if their is an easier way to do this and a lot of the other repetitive task. Thanks :D I'll put the code below:

```
from random import shuffle

class deckOfCards:
  def __init__(self):
    self.rank = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K','A']
    self.suit = ['C', 'S', 'H', 'D']
    self.deck = [r+s for r in self.rank for s in self.suit]
    shuffle(self.deck)

  def setValue(self, deck):
    cnt = 1
    self.value = {}
    for i in self.deck:
      self.value[i] = cnt
      cnt += 1

class Deal:
     def __init__(self, deck, position):
         self.hand = deck[position::4]  #divides the deck into 4 hands
         hand = self.hand
     def value(self, key):  # Gives each card that the player has a value
       newHand = {}
       for i in self.hand:
         if i in key:
           newHand[i] = key[i]
       return newHand

deck = deckOfCards()

player1 = Deal(deck.deck, 0)  #######################################
player2 = Deal(deck.deck, 1)  # Example of repetition that I wanted #
player3 = Deal(deck.deck, 2)  # to get rid of if possible           #
player4 = Deal(deck.deck, 3)  #######################################
```

EDIT: I think that this works pretty well for sorting cards but I'm still confused on how to eliminate some of the repetition. Thanks for all the help :D

```
def sortHand(player):
hand = player.hand
for i in hand:
  for i in hand:
    index = player1.hand.index(i)
    if index != 12:
      if deck.value[i] > deck.value[hand[index+1]]:
        hand.insert(index+1, hand.pop(index))
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd probably simplify this a bit:

```
from random import shuffle

class Hand(list):
  pass

class Deck(object):

  rank = '23456789TJQKA'
  suit = 'CSHD'

  def deal(self, n):
    deck = [r+s for r in Deck.rank for s in Deck.suit]
    shuffle(deck)
    return [Hand(sorted(deck[i::n], key=Deck.cmpkey)) for i in xrange(n)]

  @staticmethod
  def cmpkey(card):
    return Deck.rank.index(card[0]), Deck.suit.index(card[1])

print Deck().deal(4)
```

With this arrangement, the result of `deal()` is the list of four hands. Each hand is sorted by rank then suit.

(I didn't fully understand the "value" logic, so I've left it out of my example.)

Comment: The value is for what each card is worth, in the game I'm making a a 3C is worth less then a 5D. Eventually when I finish the game, one player will play a card and then the next player has to play a card that is worth more (has a higher value) then that one. Thanks for the response to, very helpful :D